# navigator.globalization.getLocaleName: Bug in Cordova or Firefox OS Simulator?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, globalization, firefox-os

In my Firefox OS simulator, navigator.globalization.getLocaleName() passes the locale value directly to the successCallback. According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-globalization#navigator-globalization-getlocalename) the successCallback should receive an object with the locale on the value property and on my android phone it works like this.

So is this a bug in the Firefox OS Simulator or a Cordova Bug? I'm using PhoneGap 5.3.9 with Cordova 5.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That's it - firefoxos implementation bug](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization/blob/e8baaaa8db58973c74ab44397a5c7e85ca8967dc/src/firefoxos/GlobalizationProxy.js#L96).

Please file an issue to the [Apache Cordova Jira issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB).

Comment: well spotted, thank you =) here is the [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10256)

Comment: Thank you for filing the issue!